# For all the creative people out there: coloring mandelbrot set... need ideas

Tags: colors, mandelbrot

Given max amount of iterations = 1000 give me some ideas on how to color (red, green, blue) it. All I can come up right now are lame 2 color gradients :(

Is it actually possible to come up with something as beautiful as this?

[image]

Comment: A lot of the fractal art you see out there isn't "pure" Mandelbrot set; they are often post-processed and/or rely on more calculations than just the simple iteration count. Don't be disheartened; this field is very deep if you want to go exploring!

Comment: that picture is not the usual mandelbrot set. it's sometimes called a ["buddhabrot"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhabrot)

Comment: Yep… this image looks like a composite of low-resolution plots of Mandelbrot sets of different exponents (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multibrot_set) and/or with coordinate transformations. I think genuine zoomed-in plots are nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50 iterations is very, very coarse and you won't get much detail.

The easiest way to get the spectrum is to use multiple two-color gradients. So, 50-41 iterations might be shades of blue, 41-30 might be blue-red, and 29-10 might be red-green, and 9-0 might be green-white.

An RGB monitor's gamut is triangular, so such a scheme pretty much follows the outside of the "color wheel."

A [search for HSV RGB library](http://www.google.com/search?q=hsv%20rgb%20library) might turn up tools to help use the easier HSV color system.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Potato, I'll raise it to 1000.

Comment: @Carpe: Raise it as far as you can. That should be the limiting factor on performance. Many programs adjust the threshold adaptively, so there must be easy known ways of doings so.

Comment: Fixed iteration counts are good for getting your code working. My own plotter makes multiple passes over the set, rendering between passes; it starts with a small number of iterations so it can show the user something quickly. Obviously pixels that escape play no further part in the computation; when the plot is "good enough", meaning more than some proportion of the pixels have escaped or are in the cardioid or period-2 bulb, it stops.

Answer (score 6):

Darn they won't let me a newbie post images, but to see the effect of my colouring try this link

[click to see my mandelbrot, when there right click to view larger sizes](http://www.flickr.com/photos/panzerboy/5703480708/)

My technique is to use all the available colours of the colour cube for the 228 palette indexes of Fractal extreme. Using a spreadsheet (OpenOffice) I take a linear sample of  the 24bit values. I slice 1 bit from each RGB component (ie top bit) to form a 3bit RGB value. Translate the 8 3bit colours using vlookup into a sequence like white, magenta, red, yellow, black, blue, cyan and green. I then copy and paste as values so I can then sort the top bit sequence by the 7th bit ...

Want to know the details?

Synthesizing the 24 bit RGB values is simple.
Colum A has numbers from 0 to 227, =ROW()-2
This is converted to 24bit in column B =ROUND(A2*16777215/227).
Column C converts to Hex =DEC2HEX(B2;6)
Column D extracts the red component and converts to decimal =HEX2DEC(LEFT(C2;2))
Similar for column E green =HEX2DEC(MID(C2;3;2)) and F blue =HEX2DEC(RIGHT(C2;2))
G slices the top bits and converts to a 3bit RGB
 =BIN2DEC(LEFT(DEC2BIN($D2;8);1)&LEFT(DEC2BIN($E2;8);1)&LEFT(DEC2BIN($F2;8);1))
H the 7th bit slice
=BIN2DEC(MID(DEC2BIN($D2;8);2;1)&MID(DEC2BIN($E2;8);2;1)&MID(DEC2BIN($F2;8);2;1))
I the 6th bit slice
=BIN2DEC(MID(DEC2BIN($D2;8);3;1)&MID(DEC2BIN($E2;8);3;1)&MID(DEC2BIN($F2;8);3;1))
and so on till the Lowest bit column N
 =BIN2DEC(RIGHT(DEC2BIN($D2;8);1)&RIGHT(DEC2BIN($E2;8);1)&RIGHT(DEC2BIN($F2;8);1))

Now to translate this 3bit RGB into a colour sequence I have another tab in the spreadsheet called "3bit sort".
 In column H the formula is =VLOOKUP(G2;'3bitsort'.$B$62:$C$69;2;0).
Rows b62 to b69 have the values 0, 1, 3, 2, 7, 5, 4, 6
Rows c62 to c69 have the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
So the formula translates the 3bit RGB value into its place in the sequence black, blue, cyan, green, white, magenta, red and yellow.
I do similar for the 7th thru 1st bits in columns P to V.

Now copying and pasting as values to sort on these sequenced colours would be okay but tends to have a sharp cutoff between colours. A simple sort by H by I by J... would result in top bit green 7th yellow sequenced next to top bit white 7th bit black. It would make for a smoother transition if the top bit green 7th bit white were sequenced next to top bit white 7th bit green. So I do a 2nd level of translation. This needs to translate to a different sequence based on what the higher bits colour was.
 For each colour, across the columns in "3bit sort" I create additional translation sequences based on what colour the next higher bits were.
Colum W =VLOOKUP(H2;OFFSET('3bit sort'.$E$62;0;3*O2;8;2);2;0)
The offset looks to the right of the sequence in b62:c59 used before to where I have set up the sequences I want.
O2 is the translated colour of the top bit, for green thats 3 so 9 columns to the right of b62:b69 are columns n62:n69 which contain the sequence 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 0, 5, 7
o62:o69 contain the translated sequence 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.
So if the 7th bits are white the whitest green gets sorted last.
For q62:q69 contain 2, 1, 3, 7, 0, 6, 4, 5 so the greenest white can be sorted next to the whitest green.
Copying and pasting as values then sorting by 8bit translate then by the 7th bit table indicated by the 8th bit and the 6th idicated by the 7th and so one gives a nice smoothed transition.

But I don't stop there.

Fractal Extreme can interpolate colours when the colours are spread across many iterations. The above picture has minimum iterations of 12939 and maximum of 27609 so each colour from the 228 index palette table is smeared across dozens of iterations. Fractal Extreme also has a feature where every odd colour index can come from a 2nd palette table. This gives a stripe effect. I offset the stripe palette by 16 positions, that gives the interpolation a bit of difference between colours to work with.

And that's how a legacy database hack colours a mandelbrot, he uses a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I used the [HSL/HSV colour spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) when I had the task of generating a mandelbrot set picture. You could pick the colour depending on the normalized iterations (meaning `current iteration/max iteration = colour`).

Comment: Hey that's pretty cool. I want to post an image but I need more than 10 rep, can someone do me a favor? :P

Answer (score 0):

With only 50 iterations there's something to be said for a discrete palette of colours - pick (say) 10 and simply plot each pixel as palette[itercount%palettesize]. Fiddle with the palette to make it less eye-bleeding. However, this won't work if you later transition to a smooth iteration count which requires a continuous palette. You may also want to tweak it if you go for deeper iteration counts later.

You could use HSV colouring to give a continous rainbow effect - set S=1.0, V=1.0 (or whatever you think looks good) and plot iterations (or some function of iterations) around the Hue angle. Conversion on to RGB is pretty straightforward and can be googled up.

What about multi-stage gradients? Building on the discrete palette idea, rather than just stepping from one to the next you could gradient from one to the next over some suitable range of iterations; this is better suited to larger potential iteration counts.

Answer (score 0):

I know is bit old, but my so called cyclic scheme gives interesting results on zoomed Mandelbrot parts with just 256-512-1024 iterations.

https://github.com/nmmmnu/MandelDroid/blob/master/src/nu/nmmm/android/fractal/color/FColorCyclic.java

```
public class FColorCyclic  implements FColor{
    final private static int SIZE2 = 64;
    final private static int SIZE = SIZE2 >> 1;

    @Override
    public RGB convertColor(int color, int maxcolor, RGB rgb) {
        // bounded color
        if (color == maxcolor)
            return rgb.setColorZero();

        int a = color % SIZE2;

        if (a > SIZE)
            a = SIZE2 - a;

        return rgb.setColor(a, SIZE2);
    }
}
```