# Why dont I get these amazing colors at my Mandelbrot?

Tags: java, colors, mandelbrot

This is what I am after:

[image]

This is what I make:

[image]

The problem with mine is that it just differs in color very close to the black part, then its the same constant blue. Compared to the first one where it more gradually increases into a deeper blue..

this is my color code:

```
public Generator(){
        array  = new Color[200];
        for(int k=0; k<200; k++){
            array[k]= new Color(k,k*,255);
        }
```

I made a 200 big color array, with a different color in each slot. Then I add color to every slot in my window with the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Xheight; i++) {
```

> for (int j = 0; j < Xwidth; j++) {
>
> ```
>           Complex c = new Complex(0,0);
>           Complex z = new Complex(0, 0);
>           c.add(matris[k+(resolution*i)-1][k+(resolution*j)-1]);
>           int d=0;
>
>           while(d<LordOfDoom && z.getAbs2()<4){
>
>           z.mul(z);
>           z.add(c);
>
>
>           d++;
>           }
> if (z.getAbs2()<=4 ){
>               picture[i][j]=Color.black;
>
>           }
>
>           }
>           if (z.getAbs2()>4 &&color==1 ){
>
>               picture[i][j]=array[d-1];
>           }
>
>       }
>           }
> ```

Basically it gets a picture depending on how fast z.getAbs>4.

Comment: Might be a logarithmic color scale or similar trickery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693514/for-all-the-creative-people-out-there-coloring-mandelbrot-set-need-ideas?rq=1 contains useful info wrt coloring of mandelbrot sets

Comment: I imagine that your color should correspond to the value returned from your `z.getAbs2()` method, and that this will likely cycle.